# Has any ground-based telescope taken a picture of a geostationary broadcast satellite?

Tags: telescope

I can't find 1 image, but I've heard there are a lot of geostationary satellites. Hovering in one specific spot in the sky, rotating with the Earth's spin and tilt, rotating with Earth's orbit around the Sun, and all that spinning going around galactic center. Pretty amazing stuff, I would just like to see one amateur or professional telescopic image of 1(one) of these GEOSTATIONARY SATELLITES.

Comment: [This is not an answer](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/12409/12102), but it suggests that the answer will likely be "yes". You can probably see them with small telescopes, but the hard part is pointing in the right place.

Comment: Related, there's a cool [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/space/comments/3norjc/some_geostationary_satellites_i_photographed_last/) showing geostationary satellites ina video someone took and then made a gif of.

Answer (score 13):

"Resolved images of a geostationary satellite were obtained on October 30,
2009, with the adaptive optics on the largest telescope on the planet, the 10 m
Keck-II on the 14000 foot summit of Mauna Kea."

Here ya go:

[image]

[Reference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjoztu63M7SAhVLxYMKHco0BhUQFggkMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dtic.mil%2Fget-tr-doc%2Fpdf%3FAD%3Dada531722&usg=AFQjCNGnQeO1NRLBGW2RjPGjSK0IjxbFzA&sig2=eBA624hEDzgTglj9EwWLwQ)

Comment: The use of three different scales with the units meters, arc seconds and microradians is very remarkable. The fans of imperial units might miss a fourth scale with feet, but I don't think it is necessary. The pixel size would be of interest too, I guess about 2.5 m for a pixel.

Comment: They did manage to get "feet" in when they described the mountain.  I'm holding out for furlongs!

Comment: But how many light-femtofortnights long is it?

Comment: @immibis LFFs are about 14 1/4 inches. Multiply by 0.84 to convert feet to light-femtofortnights.

Comment: I do like the unit femtofortnight.